# BASH: How to determine whether copying has finished?

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, status, cp

I need to copy files from several folders by separate `cp` commands.
How to ensure that every command ended only after what files are actually copied to disk?
How can I find out that the copying was finished?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking about interprocess-communication; you'll need to provide full details about what is calling `cp` and what needs to wait on the `cp` caller.

Comment: I always thought you were just supposed to wait until the light stopped blinking on the floppy drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly - separate your commands with &&.  Like this:

```
cp -r ./stuff/* ./somewhereelse/ && cp -r ./otherstuff/* ./somewhereelse/ && cp -r ./otherstuff/* ./anotherplace/
```

The && will ensure the next command is run on success of the previous.  You can chain as many commands as you like this way.

Comment: Ok, but how can I wait for last cp command? Then I use files for other processing and sometimes is copying to slow and files missing.

Comment: From where do you need to know that the command has completed?

Comment: For example I need to know that this part `cp -r ./otherstuff/* ./somewhereelse/` is finished and I can processed files in another program. Another program is in Node.js

Comment: Add another && and stick it on, if were still talking Bash - I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: NO, files are processed in Node.js. No in bash. That is a problem.

Comment: Then, this'll be a node.js question, won't it?  Never used Node myself.